# How to apply CSS class to a split string

Tags: jquery, html, css, xslt

I have some HTML content which are generated using XSL:

```
<span class="hrsDisp">Sunday: Closed</span>
<span class="hrsDisp">Monday &amp; Tuesday: 8 AM - 7 PM</span>
<span class="hrsDisp">Tuesday &amp; Wednesday: 7 AM - 7 PM</span>
<span class="hrsDisp">Mon, Wed, &amp; Fri: 7 AM - 5:30 PM</span>
```

XSL:

```
<span class="hrsDisp">
    <xsl:value-of select="txtHours" />
</span>
```

I am trying to set the text before the `:` to bold using JQuery. I have the following which gets the string but the alert statement only displays one alert, even though there are multiple entries:

```
$(function () {
    var theTime = $(".hrsDisp").text().split(":")[0];
    alert(theTime);
});
```

The above doesn't work as expected but doesn't throw any error either. I added the following line to add the class:

```
theTime.addClas("setBold");
```

And I get an uncaught error exception in the console.

The final script which I thought would work is:

```
$(function () {
    var theTime = $(".hrsDisp").text().split(":")[0];
    alert(theTime);
    theTime.addClass("setBold");
});
```

Instead my page is not displayed correctly and I get the error in the console.

Please help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Sorry that's a typo in the post. I am using VS so it's correct there. I will fix that now.

Comment: also you need to do $(".hrsDisp").each(function...)

Comment: Why not split it with XSL in the first place?

Comment: I am new to XSL so still not sure of the basic functionality.

Comment: https://www.google.coms/search?q=xsl%20value%20of%20select%20split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below XSL rule instead of javascript manipulation:

```
<span class="hrsDisp">
    <strong><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(txtHours, ':')" /></strong>:
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(txtHours, ':')" />
</span>
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery in this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".hrsDisp").html(function(i, old) {
        return '<strong>' + old.split(":").join('</strong>:');
    });    
});
```

Comment: There you go. That worked for me. Thanks. UPV and will accept when allowed :)

Comment: Cool. Also posted jQuery solution, although XSL is preferred of course.

Comment: Which would be faster to parse? I would like to use the faster method.

Comment: Ok nevermind. I used the XSL method and I thought it would be faster anyway as it is coming from the source :)

Comment: It's better not to give client javascript engine extra work. This is definitely job for XSL template engine.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: I tried to do it myself first but didn't succeed so HAD to ask the best community out there :)